# Compute md5 as you write million row csv file - without reading it into memory

Tags: python-3.x, stream, md5

Computing md5 needs a stream of bytes to pass through. I'm assuming it is possible to intercept csv.writer as a stream of bytes while a million rows are written. In below py code, a million rows are written, how do I compute md5 without reading the file into memory just for md5?

```
def query2csv(connection, fileUri, sqlQuery, args):
    import csv
    tocsvfile = open(fileUri, 'w+')
    writer = csv.writer(tocsvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"') # , quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
    #As a huge blob goes into writer, pass through, md5 how?
    # I do not want to read the huge file through memory just to compute md5
    with connection.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(sqlQuery, args)
        column_names = list(map(lambda x: x[0], cur.description))
        writer.writerow(column_names)
        writer.writerows(__batch_rows(cur))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) (emphasis mine):

> `csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)`
>
> Return a writer object responsible for converting the user’s data into delimited strings on the given file-like object. **`csvfile` can be any object with a `write()` method.** If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`.

So we can intercept calls to `.write()`, and feed the data into the MD5 stream, while also passing it on to the real file. The cleanest way to do this is to define a class with a `write` method which just calls some functions (i.e. one for the MD5 stream, one for the file object):

```py
import csv
import hashlib

class WriterTee:
    def __init__(self, *outs):
        self.outs = outs

    def write(self, s):
        for f in self.outs:
            f(s)

def query2csv(connection, fileUri, sqlQuery, args):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()

    with open(fileUri, 'w+', newline='') as tocsvfile, connection.cursor() as cur:
        tee = WriterTee(
            tocsvfile.write,
            lambda s: md5.update(s.encode())
        )

        writer = csv.writer(tee, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

        cur.execute(sqlQuery, args)
        column_names = list(map(lambda x: x[0], cur.description))
        writer.writerow(column_names)
        writer.writerows(__batch_rows(cur))

    return md5.hexdigest()
```

I've made a couple of other changes, to manage both resources in the `with` block, and to use `newline=''` as the docs say one should.

---

By the way, I would recommend against using MD5 for any purpose, if you have a choice. MD5 is not secure, and cryptographers have been recommending against it [since 1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#History_and_cryptanalysis). Even if you don't consider the security properties to be relevant to your application, there is no downside to using a secure hash algorithm, and the `hashlib` APIs are the same whichever algorithm you choose.

Comment: @Gayathri, Thanks for the quick complete answer. I changed md5 to sha256. Since these are locally generated shared files, I believe sha256 would suffice. blake has less name recognition at this moment.

Comment: No problem, I rolled it back.